# What's the default layout of an ImageView?

Tags: android, layout

When creating it in xml, the params layout_width and layout_height are required.
What about items created in Java code? What's their default layout? 
How can I set their layout to fill_parent or wrap_content programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> public void addView (View child)
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Adds a child view. If no layout parameters are already set on the child, the default parameters for this ViewGroup are set on the child.
>   Parameters
>   child   the child view to add
>   See Also

```
generateDefaultLayoutParams()
```

---

Without additional parameters, `addView(View)` uses the default parameters (mostly `WRAP_CONTENT`). Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#LinearLayout.generateDefaultLayoutParams%28%29),

```
protected LayoutParams  [More ...] generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    } else if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    return null;
}
```