# How to fix gridview item sizes (width and height) when I put an image on view item in Gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-gridview

I have a gridview that has multi items (buttons) I bind background for each item in my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btn;
        if (convertView == null) 
        { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            btn = new Button(mContext);
            KeypadButton keypadButton = mButtons[position];
            btn.setTag(keypadButton);
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_image);
            btn.setTextColor(android.R.color.white);
        } 
        else 
        {
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }
        btn.setText(mButtons[position].GetContent());
        return btn;
    }
```

the imageview item change it's size when I setBackgroundResource , Is it way to avoid resizing for image view item .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set LayoutParams with fixed size to avoid resizing the view

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

if you don't set LayoutParams the size will be affected by background resource size.

to get more information visit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170160/1891878