# Dynamically created ImageView is stretched when created

Tags: java, android, dynamic, view, imageview

In my android app I dynamically create ImageViews based on whether the user has previously purchased a building or not. (The buildings are the images). My issue with this is that when the ImageView is created, the image is being stretched the ImageView appears huge. I don't know why it would do this since I do this same thing in a different part of my app and the buildings load up normal size like they should.

Here is the code for a dynamically created ImageView:

```
ImageView mainHut = new ImageView(BattleActivity.this);
mainHut.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainhut);
mainHut.setX(mainHutX);
mainHut.setY(mainHutY);
bottomLayout.addView(mainHut);
```

It is added to a FrameLayout called bottomLayout.

Here is the bottomLayou FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/gameBottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without the full layout XML this is just speculation, have you tried anything like `mainHut.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes I have tried that and it doesn't change anything. I will add the layout that the ImageView is being added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the layout parameters explicitly, so the addView() method is calling generateDefaultLayoutParams() [see: [What's the default layout of an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170132/whats-the-default-layout-of-an-imageview) ]

Specify the layout params in Java like this:

```
mainHut.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```